# Nodejs Large files submission testing

Tags: node.js, express, unit-testing, multer

I have a nodejs application that exposes endpoints for uploading files.

We are doing testing for the application by submitting 18 requests each request 2 GB file.

When the files reach the server I transfer them to SFTP, I always find out that the files are distorted and not having the full size. I tried with Multer Disk Storage; however, I can see that files are not complete in the folder where they are uploaded, same with the Memory storage.